# Set a SESSION by clicking a radio button in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, session

I have a Form on my site and part of the Form allows the user to select a colour of car.

I'd like it so once they select a radio button, it updates a session variable dynamically - using Ajax & PHP.

HTML Form:

```
<form method="post">
red: <input type="radio" name="car" value="red"><br />
blue: <input type="radio" name="car" value="blue">
</form>
```

PHP Script:

```
session_start();
$carColour = $_POST["car"] ;
```

but I'm not sure how to do this with Ajax so it doesn't leave the page.

Is this possible - and how would I achieve this?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: You should at least read some tutorials about ajax and basics about sessions. You seem to have no plan of both of them...

Comment: you can try [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) if you can use some framework.

Comment: What have you tried / where are you stuck? Basics: [Wikipedia AJAX example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29#Example)

Comment: AJAX isn't really something I know much of. I'll take a look at the link - thanks @dst!

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863619/php-radio-buttons-and-session (see accepted answer also) - found this after Googling `"session $_POST radio php form"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hi. Thanks for this. If possible, I was looking for it not to have to refresh the page, but do is asynchr..asy... dynamically.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk You're welcome. How to do it dynamically, you'd have to use JS and/or Ajax for that.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Look at this then, may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371324/updating-div-on-button-click-when-the-button-is-generated-by-clicking-on-anothe and this one http://www.developphp.com/forum/view_topic.php?cat=4&otid=39400&title=jQuery%20And%20Radio%20Buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn’t be able to do it with PHP alone, as it’s not an event-driven language. By the time you click the radio button, the PHP interpreter has been and gone.

You’ll need to use JavaScript function to call a PHP script that sets the session, and attach that function to the `onclick` event of your radio button.

Comment: *"By the time you click the radio button"*, actually, it's more like "by the time you click the Submit button" ;-)